# Dudas con SubmitChanges en Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wpf

Muy buenas a todos,

Estoy empezando a jugar con Linq to Sql y no he terminado de ver detalles y ejemplo sobre el tema, por lo que me suguen algunas preguntas:

- Por las primeras impresiones, parece que le gana a las conexiones habituales hacia la base de datos.

– Hasta que no lanzo SubmitChanges, no se aplican los cambios y este se aplica al datacontext completo. Con lo cual puedo estar variando varias tablas y supongo que cuando lanzo SubmitChanges es cuando se cambian todas, ¿verdad?

– Al lanzar SubmitChanges, supongo que sólo lanzo los cambios, por lo que debo entender que no será muy lento para bases de datos de buen tamaño ¿?.

– Supongo que si mientras trabajo en el datacontext, si otro usuario cambia un elemento de los que no he modificado, pues no me enteraré, pues al enviarlo, sólo cambiará los que yo he modificado ¿?.

– Si envío unos cambios y mientras otro usuario ha modificado esos mismos elementos, ¿qué pasará?

Son algunas dudillas que me han surgido mientras trasteaba. Un saludo a todos.